# CSS layout - 2px missing?

Tags: css

Okay.. I have to build a css layout for a class. Anyway, first of all, here is the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="vrstica ena">
            <div class="vsebina ena"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="vrstica dve">
            <div class="vsebina ena"></div>
            <div class="vsebina dve"></div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
.container {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Splosni stili */
.vsebina {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #FAC6C6;
}


/* Prva vrstica */
.vrstica.ena .vsebina.ena {
    height: 160px;
}

/* Druga vrstica */
.vrstica.dve {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.vrstica.dve .vsebina.ena {
    float:left;
    height: 160px;
    width: 450px;
}

.vrstica.dve .vsebina.dve {
    float: right;
    height: 160px;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 7px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

As you can see from this screenshot aswell, 2px are missing from 2nd column item in 2nd row: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOZ7e.png

As soon as I remove box-sizing property, they are both same height again.

Edit: Question: Why is the box with class "vsebina dve" 2px shorter than "vsebina ena", when I add box-sizing?

Comment: what is the Q.?

Comment: Why is the box with class "vsebina dve" 2px shorter than "vsebina ena", when I add box-sizing?

Comment: @miqro because that's how the box model works. The top/bottom 1px border creates 2px height. `box-sizing: border-box;` keeps padding and border from affecting the element's height/width.

Comment: Oooh, right. Dont know how I didnt see that. Thanks tho. You can answer again below if u want, and I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks.